# CheckboxSelectMultiple Django extract if checked or not

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck on the "CheckboxSelectMultiple", I don't know how to extract what the user selected and what not.

for example, my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
)


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

my views.py:

```
from accounts.forms import MyForm

def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                if request.POST["favorite_colors"]:
                    print(request.POST["favorite_colors"])
            except:
                print(request.POST["favorite_colors"])
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form})
```

currently, it gives me the last selected checkbox, how can i check if specific checkbox was selected? (for example 'if request.POST["favorite_colors.blue"]: print('blue')' or something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this ?

```
def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Selected: " + form.cleaned_data['favorite_colors'])
        else:
            print("error")

    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: awesome, it works! (just needed to modify it from list to str)what actually cleaned_data does? it takes the info from the form objects and storage them in a list?

Comment: Learn more about it here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)

Comment: Yea, It stores as a dictionary actually. Then you can access them via the keys.